# how an as/400 recognizes the encoding of a file? cat prints correctly two different encodings

Tags: unix, ibm-midrange

In QSHELL, I do cat of two files with the same text in different encodings, and both print the same content, look (hell.txt is EBCDIC and hellascii.txt is ASCII):

> cat hellascii.txt
> hello @@@@@@@

> cat hell.txt
> hello @@@@@@@

> od -x hell.txt
> 0000000  4040 4040 8885 9393 9640 7c7c 7c7c 7c7c
> 0000020  7c25
> 0000022

> od -x hellascii.txt
> 0000000  2020 2020 6865 6c6c 6f20 4040 4040 4040
> 0000020  4000
> 0000021

In my laptob, in linux or mac, EBCDIC encoding shows other characters that look messed up. How the unix in as400 can print both correctly? I do not see anything such as a file header that indicates the encoding. For example, 0x40 is @ in ascii and space in EBCDIC, but cat prints correctly in hell.txt the 0x40 as space and in hellascii.txt as @.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On IBM i, the system keeps track of the CCSID assigned to each IFS file. You can see the CCSID by using the -C option of od.  Here is an example.

```
$ od -tx -C helloascii.txt
helloascii.txt CCSID = 819
0000000  68692074 68657265 0a000000
0000011
$ od -tx -C helloebcdic.txt
helloebcdic.txt CCSID = 256
0000000  888940a3 88859985 25000000
0000011
```

You can assign the CCSID of a new file using the -C option of touch.  Here is how I created the files used above.

```
$ touch -C 819 helloascii.txt
$ echo 'hi there' >> helloascii.txt
$ touch -C 256 helloebcdic.txt
$ echo 'hi there' >> helloebcdic.txt
```